# Qt renaming path of the project

Tags: qt, project, rename, qt5.2

sometimes when I rename the path to a qt project, it cannot be run even though I clean qmake and rebuild it!!! the path does not contain any space. and the project is completely correct and I know that the error is for path renaming , for example when I rename :

> D:/abd/projects/LAND_2/Land_QT/...

to

> D:/abd/projects/LAND_2/Land2_QT_SA/...

it cannot  be build and says that some include file is missing(but the file is there!).

what is the problem?

I work with dynamic qt5.2 on windows 7.

Edit:
when I copy the project folder to a new directory( a path upper than current path) then the project can be build and run.

Comment: Maybe some paths are hardcoded in your pro file(s)?

Comment: @vahancho , No I use $$PWD for path and there is no hardcoded path,

Comment: could this be caused by some shadow build mess? Have you renamed also shadow build path?

Comment: Try to remove all Makefile(s) and run qmake again before build.

Comment: I do all of them, but the problem exists.

Answer (score 3):

When you rename the path to the project, go to the project folder and delete the file with **.pro.user** extension. Open the project and Qt will ask you to configure the project. Choose the required kit, build and run the project.It should build successfully now

Comment: there must be some information about the project you're trying to build you haven't shared with us yet because this works all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed path multiple times the .pro.user file is created multiple times delete all files with this extension and compile